# Optimizing routing table size and a number of hops

Tags: networking, routes

I have a bidirectional ring network topology with 9 routers. What would you suggest to reduce the size (number of rows) in a routing table, and a number of hops?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a dynamic routing protol such as OSPF or RIP / EIGRP .
using HSRP for switches : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Standby_Router_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

I think what confusing you is that if every two of the nodes build a connection, the network may become comlpex.

Firstly, since the topology is small, a controller may be a good choice for you. If you don't want it, then you can use some algorithm like dijkstra, OSPF, RIP, or something others like ants colony algorithm, genetic algorithm which can work well in large network.